# Error 404 when you refresh a Next.js page

Tags: reactjs, next.js, http-status-code-404, refresh

I am getting this error whenever I try to refresh a routed page in my small Next.js app.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I solved it by adding an hash before the href url, such as `<Link href='#/link'>`

Comment: It not work for me

Comment: @albert There have been new updates between then and now. I don't even think the problem still exists in the new update.